# find_library chooses the static library instead of the shared library

Tags: dll, cmake, mingw

This [has been asked on SO before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3537588/issue-on-using-cmake-with-msys-mingw-linking-dll-files-using-devil-image-library?rq=1) and there's even [a related bug on this in CMAKE](https://cmake.org/Bug/view.php?id=1643).  However, my issue is a variation and the answer is not clear.

My wrinkle is that I'm cross-compiling for Windows on Linux using MinGW.  Static libs are named like this `libGLESv2.dll.a` and `libiconv.dll.a` for the DLLs `libGLESv2.dll` and `iconv.dll` respectively.

Examples:

```
find_library(FOUND_LIB_X NAMES "zlib1.dll" PATHS ${CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH}/bin/)
finds this: zlib1.dll

find_library(FOUND_LIB_Y NAMES "libGLESv2.dll" PATHS ${CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH}/bin/)
finds this: libGLESv2.dll.a

find_library(FOUND_LIB_Y NAMES "iconv.dll" PATHS ${CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH}/bin/)
finds this: libiconv.dll.a
```

[The CMAKE bug](https://cmake.org/Bug/view.php?id=1643) seems to be referring to traditional situations where the static lib is named blah.lib (Windows) or blah.a (Linux).  In this cross-compiler situation with mingw on Linux, they are named blah.dll.a

I need it to find the file literally called `iconv.dll` and nothing else.  If it doesn't literally find that, then abort.  Am I using the wrong CMAKE function? (don't use `find_library()`?)

Comment: Strange. According to [documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.6/command/find_library.html), `Each library name given to the NAMES option is first considered as a library file name and then considered with platform-specific prefixes (e.g. lib) and suffixes (e.g. .so).`. Are you sure that it finds `libiconv.dll.a` **in the same directory**, which contains `iconv.dll`? At last resort you may clean variable `CMAKE_FIND_LIBRARY_PREFIXES` or `CMAKE_FIND_LIBRARY_SUFFIXES` before `find_library` call.

Comment: BTW, you clean CMake cache before every reconfiguration for allow `find_library` to find something *new*, don't you?

Comment: @Tsyvarev -- a file literally called iconv.dll is in the /bin folder specified in the PATHS parameter.  Another file literally called libiconv.dll.a is in /lib which is parallel to /bin.   Yes, I clear the cache.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CMake uses **definite order** between iterating library names and directories when search the library. E.g., according to [documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.6/command/find_library.html),

> When more than one value is given to the NAMES option this command by default will consider one name at a time and search every directory for it.

That is, with libraries at `dir1/name2` and `dir2/name1`

```
find_library(MYLIB NAMES name1 name2 PATHS dir1 dir2)
message(${MYLIB})
```

will print `dir2/name1`.

Specifying *NAMES_PER_DIR* option reverse the choice:

```
find_library(MYLIB NAMES name1 name2 NAMES_PER_DIR PATHS dir1 dir2)
message(${MYLIB})
```

will print `dir1/name2`.

Things are different with trying library's prefix and suffix:

> Each library name given to the NAMES option is first considered as a library file name and then considered with platform-specific prefixes (e.g. lib) and suffixes (e.g. .so).

It seems that checking for `lib<name>.so` is performed immediately after `<name>` **when iterating directories**.

That is, with libraries at `dir1/libname.so` and `dir2/name`

```
find_library(MYLIB NAMES name PATHS dir1 dir2)
message(${MYLIB})
```

will print `dir1/libname.so`.

That is why `libiconv.dll.a` is found in your case: `lib/` directory is searched as system specific path at step 5 of `find_library` search algorithm, but directory `bin/`, specified as PATH option, is searched only at step 6.

The simplest way to find what you want is to use *NO_DEFAULT_PATH* option, so searching in `lib/` will not be performed at all:

```
find_library(FOUND_LIB_Y
    NAMES "iconv.dll"
    PATHS ${CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH}/bin/
    NO_DEFAULT_PATH
)
```