# cmake find_library without "lib" prefix name

Tags: linux, cmake

I have a library called `mylib.a` in the path `/home/test/libs/`.

How can I add it to the project??

```
find_library(IDA_LIB
                 NAMES "mylib.a"
                 PATHS "/home/test/libs"
                 NO_DEFAULT_PATH)
```

Since it does not have the prefix `lib` cmake does not find it. If I change the library name to `libmylib.a` if finds it fine.

Comment: You note `add_library` in the title, but the problem is with `find_library()`.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39687754/find-library-chooses-the-static-library-instead-of-the-shared-library (also problem with library's prefix).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use following command with absolute file path of your library

```
target_link_libraries(IDA_LIB /home/test/libs/mylib.a)
```

Comment: That doesn't work. I've already tried it. The parameter passed to the linker is -lmylib.a and still tries to find `libmylib.a`

Comment: @user1618465 try providing full path

Comment: This doesn't work also when using a variable created by ``find_library``.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
add_library(mylib STATIC IMPORTED)
set_target_properties(mylib PROPERTIES IMPORTED_LOCATION /home/test/mylib.a)
```

then you can use "mylib" in:

```
target_link_libraries(myapp
        mylib )
```